# Cant access environmental variables React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make my login re-usable by storing enviromental variables in .env.local. However whenever I try to call these variables I get undefined.

here is my .env.local file

```
REACT_APP_AMARBIS_API_KEY = classified
REACT_APP_AMARBIS_AUTH_DOMAIN = classified
REACT_APP_AMARBIS_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID = classified
REACT_APP_AMARBIS_STORAGE_BUCKET = classified
REACT_APP_AMARBIS_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID = classified
REACT_APP_AMARBIS_APP_ID = classified
```

and here is where I am trying to access them

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import "firebase/auth"

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AMARBIS_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_AMARBIS_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_AMARBIS_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_AMARBIS_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_AMARBIS_APP_ID
})

export const auth = app.auth()
export default app
```

Comment: I asume you're using dotenv npm package?

Comment: Yes I used create react app then even just tried installing it manually later.

Comment: sometimes you have to restart your app manually specially when using enviroment variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to stop your development server and re-run it using npm start. Each time you update your .env file, you'd need to do this, else you'll get undefined when you try to use the environment variables in your project

Comment: I figured that out right before I saw this. Thanks a ton this was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

So I think the problem was that I couldnt change these during a run and all references to them had to be set during startup.